# Is there a more efficient to write to Excel from C# project

Tags: c#, excel

I have code that will write from C7 to Q21 and when that gets full moves to V7 to AJ21. My code now has two for loops. The first one writes from C7 to Q21 and if that gets full the second one moves to the next range. The code is pretty much identical and seems inefficient.
Here is a sample of what I have:

```
bool found = false;
for (int rowNum = 8; rowNum < 21; rowNum++)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(summarySheet.Cells[rowNum, 3].Value)))
    {
       summarySheet.Cells[rowNum, 3].Value = runNumber;
       summarySheet.Cells[rowNum, 4].Value = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
       found = true;
    }
}
if (found == false)
{
    for (int rowNum = 8; rowNum < 21; rowNum++)
    {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(summarySheet.Cells[rowNum, 22].Value)))
       {
          summarySheet.Cells[rowNum, 22].Value = runNumber;
          summarySheet.Cells[rowNum, 23].Value = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
          found = true;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to provide valid C# code. This `bool found == false;` does not seem valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. In order to see the duplication even better, we can introduce additional code that does nothing. It's like math: you can always add 0 or multiply by 1 without changing anything.

```
bool found == false;
if (found == false)       //  <-- always true, does nothing

    for (int rowNum = 8; rowNum < 21; rowNum++)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(summarySheet.Cells[rowNum, 3].Value)))
        {
           summarySheet.Cells[rowNum, 3].Value = runNumber;
           summarySheet.Cells[rowNum, 4].Value = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
           found = true;
        }
    }

}
if (found == false)
{
    for (int rowNum = 8; rowNum < 21; rowNum++)
    {
       if (true)  // <-- always true, does nothing
       {
           summarySheet.Cells[rowNum, 22].Value = runNumber;
           summarySheet.Cells[rowNum, 23].Value = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
           found = true;
       }
    }
}
```

Now you can do some refactoring. Begin on the innermost level and introduce variables:

```
int column = 3;
summarySheet.Cells[rowNum, column].Value = runNumber;
summarySheet.Cells[rowNum, column+1].Value = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
found = true;

[...]

int column = 22;
summarySheet.Cells[rowNum, column].Value = runNumber;
summarySheet.Cells[rowNum, column+1].Value = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
found = true;
```

Now you have 3 identical lines that you can extract into a method. Replace the same code by the same method.

Next, inline the temporarily introduced variable.

```
found = SetCells(summarySheet, rowNum, 3, runNumber);
[...]
found = SetCells(summarySheet, rowNum, 22, runNumber);
[...]
bool SetCells(summarySheet, rowNum, column, runNumber) 
{
    summarySheet.Cells[rowNum, column].Value = runNumber;
    summarySheet.Cells[rowNum, column+1].Value = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    return true;
}
```

Extract the if condition as a local variable.

Extract the if statement as a method.

Extract the for loop as a method.